# How do I use multiple python files for one program that only contains one tkinter window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently undertaking a project that can only use one Tkinter window and must have multiple python files. I am trying to do this but have no clue how to get a different python window to use the same window. I have code for the tkinter window in the main.py being initialized as:

```
lib = tk.Tk()

lib.geometry("500x400")
lib.resizable(False, False)

lib.title("Library Management System")
```

and this files also contains modules that all work perfectly well

Then i try to use this window in another file called search.py with some code which is called upon within main.py such as:

```
search = tk.Text(lib,
                   height = 5,
                   width = 20 )
```

and an error message appears as follows:

options = tk.Label(lib,
^^^
NameError: name 'lib' is not defined

I have imported filename and it still won't work

Any help would be really apprechiated.

Comment: you could either `import filename` to get access from one file to another or create a new instance of `lib`

Comment: It's best to have one main Python file that handles your GUI / tkinter functions, and then import functions from your other files as needed. E.g.: in search.py `def search(): '<whatever your search function does>'`, and then in main.py `from search import search`, etc.